# WSDL provided by the client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, wsdl

I am trying to build a payment system while integrating with a Bank **`X`**. **`X`** has provided me with a WSDL link to access the service which defines 2 operations(`o1` and `o2`). When I send a request to **`o1`** or **`o2`**, the request fails with **`SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)`**.

The reason they are giving for this is that these operations will not work unless I provide a WSDL from my side. This is where I am confused. I am the consumer of the web service so what kind of WSDL should I be providing exactly. Am I missing something here? This is the first time I am using SOAP so before I raise any questions to **`X`** on behalf of my company, I want to know if I am on the right track.

EDIT

I cannot disclose the name of the bank since it is a private integration but, I can give the API details. There is a WSDL endpoint which returns two operations, **`pay`** and **`rev`**. **`pay`** is used to initiate a payment(immediate response, no hooks or callbacks) and **`rev`** is used to get the status of any transaction. The parameters that needs to be sent to **`pay`** and **`rev`** are defined in the API doc. Now, the WSDL returns the operations however, request to **`pay`** and **`rev`** fails as I mentioned above and the reason given by them is that they need a WSDL from our side. So what I want to know is, to consume a web service does a client need to provide a WSDL as well? I know that should not be the case, I just want to be sure.

Comment: Payment provider usually expect that you provide some callback routes. For example a route which they should call when a payment was successfully. Only your bank can tell you what kind of callbacks they support or expect.

Comment: There are no callbacks specified in the document, they mentioned responses are real time and also **`o2`** provides the status of a transaction, so ideally we are not exposing any web service from our side. So, that is why I don't get what will the WSDL contain even if we provide one.

Comment: You did not even tell us the name of the bank. How should we be able to answer that question? Why don't you ask your payment provider?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to answer this question without knowing the name of the bank or having more information about the API.